# Using iPhone device as a test device

Tags: iphone, testing, device

I have 2 newbie questions:

Can I use my iPhone for both personal and test purposes?
Can the tests damage my iPhone, even if I try to fix all bugs in simulator first?

Thanks for the attention and patience guys! =D

Comment: `Can the tests damage my iPhone, even if I try to fix all bugs in simulator first?` - This seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of software development. I would suggesting starting from the very basics.

Comment: The answer is actually very simple, yes and no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use your device for personal as well testing purpose only thing is to test on the device you will have to buy a developer account from Apple which cost $99 for one year. No the test is not going to damage your phone. If there is any bug the app crashes (not all the bug cause the Crash, screen freezes etc.) but that is not going to damage your device.